# How can I count and select at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to do a `select` and `count` at the same time.

This is my code:

```
@count = Policy.find(:all,:conditions=>['state= 0 AND deleted = 0']

####i want to count all the policies  that has 1 client by document

@count =   Policy.count(:joins => :client,:conditions => ['doc_jur LIKE ? OR doc_nat LIKE ?', "%#{params[:doc]}%","%#{params[:doc]}%" ])
```

How can I do this in only one line (one action)?

I want:

```
 SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `policies` 
 where state= 0 AND deleted = 0
 INNER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.id = `policies`.client_id 
 WHERE (doc_jur LIKE '%20535920746%' OR doc_nat LIKE '%20535920746%')
```

Comment: what version of rails are you using? looks like syntax for 2 - some of this can be done easier in newer versions

Comment: yes version 2 that's why i tagged 2

Comment: Are You sure You specified a valid SQL statement? Do I understand You correctly - You need to count policies that have ONLY one client and which satisfy both conditions - `where state= 0 AND deleted = 0` and `(doc_jur LIKE '%20535920746%' OR doc_nat LIKE '%20535920746%') ` ?

Comment: yes but is not working

Comment: Have You tried adding those conditions together in Your second statement? It should issue count request with all conditions as You want it. Or You want a single query that would return all policies and their number as separate column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  @count =Policy.count(:joins => :client,:conditions => ['policies.state=0 AND policies.deleted= 0 AND clients.doc_jur LIKE ? OR clients.doc_nat LIKE ?', "%#{params[:doc]}%","%#{params[:doc]}%" ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Ruby:

```
@policies = Policy.find(:all,:conditions=>['state= 0 AND deleted = 0'])
count = @policies.length
```